# Are expired session ids recycled using express-session

Tags: node.js, express, session-state

Coming from the ASP.NET world, I'm used to there being a setting to determine whether or not expired session ids for cookieless sessions are recycled or not. Is something to be concerned about with express-session in Node? I'm going to guess not, since from what I can tell even if you are using Redis with express-session it still uses a cookie to store the session id. Just wanted to confirm with someone with more expertise than me that this is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not recycled. Not by default, at least.

Express generates [cryptographically secure random UID](https://www.npmjs.org/package/uid-safe) for each new session, [signs it](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cookie-signature) and then stores signed id in user's cookies.

But you can use your own UID generator [by passing it in `options.genid`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#optionsgenid). So, I think its possible to build a system with recyclable ids in express..

Since express often [use redis to store session data](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-redis), I see no reason to recycle session ids.